# RegexValidator for name and surname

Tags: regex

How should like a regex which validates the name and surname, so that each word starts with a capital letter?
this does not work: @"[^A-Z]?[a-z]*"

Thanks

Comment: What about names such as "de Broglie"?

Comment: Yes.. you may be best off just watching for special characters and assuming that people type their own names correctly.

Comment: Don't do it at all. It's impossible to anticipate all the weird cases as O'Reilly and "de Broglie" (as suggested by @Seth) or the Danish last name of Sørensen. You can't expect people's names to be confined to ASCII. Also, people tend to spell their name correctly.

Comment: Also what about the hyphen/dash: `Jean-Yves`, apostrophe: `O'Connor` and whitespace: `Abdul Rahman (first name consist of two words)`.

Comment: Just make sure people don't spell their name like so: http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: No, it's about a simple regex, so i'm interested only in A-Z letters, any words, but each word should start with a capital letter.
'Ackjq ff' for example should not be valid. Any regex?

Comment: Check [this validation regex](https://regex101.com/r/NQF5zP/20)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
[A-Z][a-z]*
```

Note that this is, however, not a good way to validate names. Depending on the locale, non-ASCII UTF8 characters may be used. Also, not all names start with an uppercase letter. The following names exist in the real world:

```
Martha de Lange Norton
Marcél du Toit
```

Hence, this is a little better - it just makes sure that each character is a valid letter:

```
\p{L}+
```

That said, the best way to do this may depend on the implementation of the regular expression engine, so we'd need to know the language and/or regex library that you are using.

**Edit based on your answer**: If you need to parse both fields at the same time, try this:

```
^[A-Z][a-z]*\s[A-Z][a-z]*$
```

Comment: @"" defines a string literal in C#, eliminating the need to do double escaping. Helpful for regexes. (Although it's superfluous for the OP's regex since there are no special characters.)

Comment: So i have:

[RegexValidator(@"[A-Z][a-z]*", MessageTemplate = "Name must be valid!", Ruleset="validate_name")]

And the test passes with "laddf Ghu" for example, which is not correct (laddf does not start with capital letter).

Answer (score 0):

That states that it does NOT start with one or more capitals. `^` within the character class means negation... `[^A-Z]` means everything except capitals. Outside of the brackets, it means 'beginning of the string', which I assume is what you intended. You want this:

`^[A-Z]?[a-z]*` for one or more of capitals at the beginning, or

`^[A-Z][a-z]*` for exactly one capital, or

`^[A-Z][A-Za-z]*` for capitals anywhere, but definitely one at the beginning.

Comment: I would go with the last one since McGregor is a legal name. But don't forget about O'Reilly.